# Making conclusion slide beamer using Rmarkdown

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown

I am trying to make a conclusion slide like this one in beamer using Rmarkdown. However, I want to make the blue rectangle at the left side of the slide with the grey one following it. The problem is that I cannot make these two rectangles. The frame title is still in place and I cannot remove it even if I try to use in the YAML header:

```
- \makeatletter
- \def\ps@navigation@conclusion{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white, fg = white}\@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
- \makeatother
```

and use `\thispagestyle{navigation@conclusion}` on the right slide.

The rectangle also does not want to start in the bottom left corner of the slide. I am using this code now. The color of the rectangle should be the blue I defined as BlueM but that does not work either.

```
### Conclusion
\thispagestyle{navigation@conclusion}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,0) rectangle (5,20);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know I can make the points with `\draw[fill=white] (5.8,2) circle (0.6) node[align=center]{\includegraphics[width=0.07\textwidth]{FIGURE}};` but I do not know how I can make them start at the end of the grey rectangle. Also how to align the text next to the points is a question for me.

When using `\draw[fill=white] (5.8,2) circle (0.6) node[align=center]{\includegraphics[width=0.07\textwidth]{FIGURE}}`. The figure is [image]

Can someone help me?

This is the theme I am using right now:

```
output: 
    beamer_presentation:
        latex_engine: xelatex
        theme: "metropolis"
        slide_level: 3
navigation: horizontal 
classoption: "aspectratio=169"
header-includes:
     - \metroset{block=fill}
     - \useoutertheme{infolines}
     - \usepackage{xcolor}
     - \definecolor{GreenM}{RGB}{107, 169, 36}
     - \definecolor{BlueM}{RGB}{6, 48, 96}
     - \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg = GreenM}
     - \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{date}{fg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{progress bar in section page}{fg = GreenM,bg = gray}

     - \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=GreenM, fg = white}
     - \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=GreenM}
     - \setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=red}
     - \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=BlueM, bg=white}
     - \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=BlueM}
     - \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=BlueM}
```

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted so quickly? It needs improvement sure but they're a new user

Comment: @Maries Please add a minimal reproducible example to your question in which we can see how far you got yourself and so that we don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Please also show which elements are covered by your `FIGURE` image.

Comment: Please also add which theme you use. Normally the frametitle is only shown wehen you explicitly add it to this frame. Without knowing your theme and how you managed to make the frametitle persistent, your question as it is does not make a lot of sense. Also don't just talk about "this rectangle" etc. It is unclear if you mean the gray one, the blue one, something else?

Comment: My apologies, I made the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `remember picture` option for your `tikzpicture`, you can position your rectangles etc with respect to the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[white] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\fill[blue!40!black] (current page.south) rectangle (current page.north east);
\fill[lightgray!30] (current page.south) rectangle ([xshift=1.25cm]current page.north);

% red circle
\node[fill=red,draw=white,circle,font=\color{white}\Huge,ultra thick] (1) at ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north) {1};
\node[left=of 1,anchor=east,text width=.3\textwidth,align=left] {\textbf{Conclusions}\\some other text};

% blue circle
\node[fill=blue!40!black,draw=white,circle,font=\color{white}\Huge,ultra thick,below=of 1] (2) {2};
\node[left=of 2,anchor=east,text width=.3\textwidth,align=left] {\textbf{Conclusions}\\some other text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Marie You're welcome!

Comment: @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz with the theme I use do you know how I can change the date to a certain date written as "May 17,2023". Now the date is displayed as 2022/2023 which is not really what I want. So that it is correctly specified on the title slide and the footer of all slides?

Comment: @Marie If you have a new question, please ask a new question. In Latex it would be a one line job, but in rmarkdown it will require some code and comments are not a good place to share this code with you.